# Mongodb use foreach on query and update results its results

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collection where a field is supposed to point to another document's id in the same collection, but instead it is pointing to its "number". I need to perform an update on them but I'm having some problems on forming the query. Could you help me?

The structure of the document is like this:

```
{
  "_id": "269410e2-cebf-40f1-a81f-fdce34185cdc",
  "number": 1471,
  "alternativeLocationId": "9871",
  "locationType": "DUMMY"
},
{
  "_id": "2945b24a-b82f-45a9-ad06-a884379b5597",
  "number": 9871,
  "locationType": "MAIN"
}
```

So as asked, I'd need to make document with number 1471 "alternativeLocationId" to be "2945b24a-b82f-45a9-ad06-a884379b5597" instead of 9871 (Note that the referenced documents are not locationType "DUMMY" nor have this alternativeLocationId field).

The query I've done so far goes like this, but when executed its not doing any changes:

```
db.location.find({alternativeLocationId: {$exists:true}}).forEach(
    function (loc) {
        var correctLocation = db.location.findOne({number: loc.alternativeLocationId});
        db.location.update(
            {_id: loc._id},
            {$set: {alternativeLocationId: correctLocation._id} }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: Well at least one problem here s the type mismatch.  `alternativeLocationId` is stored as a string but `number` is a number.  If you are going to do this as a client-side `.forEach()` loop (which may be quite slow, how many documents will you be updating?), then you could do the string->number conversion via javascript in the client before it goes back to the server (in the `findOne()` line)

Comment: Thank you! That was actually the problem, after parsing the value to int it worked perfectly. And its not a lot of records, 50 or so I believe.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [user20042973](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20042973/user20042973) the issue was the type mismatch between alternativeLocationId and locationNumber, after converting the value to int when looking for it, it works perfectly.